# I'm trying to create a program that will convert 2 (user) inputs to lists and then print the duplicates in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason the program prints the duplicates but not all of them.
For example if `list1 = 'test'` and `list2 = 'test'` it prints `['t','e','s']`

```
dublicates = []
x = input('type something : ')
y = input('type something again : ')
list1 = list(x)
list2 = list(y)
for i in list2:
    if i not in dublicates:
        dublicates.append(i)
print (dublicates)
end = input('press enter to exit')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial logic doesn't work since when it gets to the last character `t`, it is already present in `duplicates` list, so `if i not in duplicates:` is evaluated to `False` and the last `t` is not added to the `duplicates` list

Instead for your duplicate logic, you should check if a character in `x` is present in `y` or not, if it is present, add it to the `duplicates` list, also you don't need to convert `string` to a `list` rather you can iterate on the characters directly

```
duplicates = []
x = input('type something : ')
y = input('type something again : ')

#Iterate through x
for i in x:
    #For every character in x, check if it present in y
    if i in y:
        duplicates.append(i)

print(duplicates)
end = input('press enter to exit')
```

The output will be

```
type something : test
type something again : test
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to exit
```

A similar list comprehension way to get the duplicates will be

```
duplicates = [ i for i in x if i in y]
```